# How to programmatically get all nodes which are related to the specific term ID?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

**What I want to do?**

I want to display all **categories** in first drop down and in second all **titles** of related nodes with the selected **category**.

To get that I have mentioned all the tasks I have done. Please read below.

1. Created taxonomy named `category` with terms listed `Laptop`, `Car`, `Mobile` etc.
2. Content type named `product` with fields `title`, `description`, `category` etc. The `category` field uses **term reference** of `category` taxonomy.
3. Created a form with [WebForm](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) with fields named `category` and `product`as drop down
4. First, `categories` drop down field, displayed all categories (Laptop, Car, Mobile) by using [WebForm Term Options](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_term_opts).
5. Second, `product` drop down field  is empty yet.

I have used [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) hook to alter the webForm I created. I have found the [solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99248/programmatically-getting-custom-node-belonging-to-a-term#answer-100205) to get all the nodes pragmatically those are related with specific taxonomy term ID.

**My first question is how to display all these nodes' titles in existing drop down field?**

**Another question is on `category` change, `products` must be change according to its nodes like ajax?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on Drupal Stack Exchange. Here is the solution
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225840/how-to-programmatically-get-all-nodes-which-are-related-to-the-specific-term-id/225855?noredirect=1#225855